# Problems displaying images from Firebase Storage /Hosting using Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm pamanndo for a few hours to try to understand why the image is displayed locally, but is not being printed on the page in production.

I used as a guide the repo `https://github.com/ankeshs/next-firebase-boilerplate`, I made some updates and updated the files to the default coming from the `yarn create next-app`.

I added to the `next.config.js` the infos:

```
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    formats: [
      'image/avif',
      'image/webp'
    ],
    domains: [
      'firebasestorage.googleapis.com',
      'site-vofstudio.appspot.com'
    ]
  }
```

and on the image import kept as:

```
<Image   
    src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/site-vofstudio.appspot.com/o/structure%2Fvercel.svg?alt=media&token=8cc0db35-06f0-4781-ae5c-4d7ef222650e" 
    alt="Pinguen Linux" 
    width={104} height={120} 
    blurDataURL="data:..." 
    placeholder="blur" 
    automatically provided 
/>
```

Locally, everything is in order, but in production, the image does not load.

Can anyone help me or know what is the most effective way to display the image in prod?

Comment: This may be related to your problem: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19065

Comment: What does "pamanndo" mean? Is it supposed to be "pamando", meaning "pawing"? Should "I'm pamanndo" be instead "I've been trying"?